# C function that returns a string describing growth rate

Tags: c, function

I have to create a function in C where the parameter is a double (growth rate) and I have to return a string as a const char* describing the growth rate. For example if the growth rate is 2.9 it would return a string that says "high"

So far this is what I have,

```
const char *get_growth_rate_description(double growth_rate) {

  char *description;
  double growth_percentage = growth_rate * 100;

  if (growth_rate < 0) {
    char *description = "Negative";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 0 && growth_rate < 1) {
    char *description = "reasonable";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 1 && growth_rate < 2) {
    char *description = "ambitious";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 2 && growth_rate < 4) {
    char *description = "high";
  } else {
    char *description = "unreasonable";
  }

  return description;
}

int main(void) {

  double growth = calculate_growth_rate(27367, 40000, 2022, 2035);

  const char *description = get_growth_rate_description(growth);

  printf("%s", description);
}
```

I get a warning that says description is uninitialized and if I try and run the program in my main driver this is what prints "0\365\337o"

Comment: Aside, why do you check `>= 0` when you already know that to be true from the previous condition? And ditto for all the other conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're declaring a new, different, if similarly named, `char *description` in each of those `if`/`else if` branches, and hence, the top-level `description` indeed remains uninitialized.

Since you're returning a constant string, you can just do

```
const char *get_growth_rate_description(double growth_rate) {
  if (growth_rate < 0) {
    return "Negative";
  }
  if (growth_rate < 1) {
    return "reasonable";
  }
  if (growth_rate < 2) {
    return "ambitious";
  } 
  if (growth_rate < 4) {
    return "high";
  }
  return "unreasonable";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`char *description;` is not initialized.

Then you define new `description` variables in the `if` statements scope, but they stop existing outside those scopes and you return the `description` defined in the function scope and this one was not initialized.

You need to remove `char *` from assignments

```
const char *get_growth_rate_description(double growth_rate) {

  char *description;
  double growth_percentage = growth_rate * 100;

  if (growth_rate < 0) {
    description = "Negative";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 0 && growth_rate < 1) {
    description = "reasonable";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 1 && growth_rate < 2) {
    description = "ambitious";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 2 && growth_rate < 4) {
    description = "high";
  } else {
    description = "unreasonable";
  }
  return description;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the variable `growth_percentage` declared like

```
double growth_percentage = growth_rate * 100;
```

is not used in the function.

As the return type pf the function is `const char *` then it will be more logically consistent to declare the variable `description` also as having the type `const char *`.

```
const char *description;
```

Within sub-statements of each if statement you are declaring new variables with the sane name `description` that hide the variable declared before the set of if statements. So the variable stays uninitialized and it is this variable that is returned from the function.

Instead of declaration of new variables in of statement you need to use assignment statement to assign string literals to the variable declared before the set of if statements.

```
const char * get_growth_rate_description(double growth_rate) {

  const char *description;
  double growth_percentage = growth_rate * 100;

  if (growth_rate < 0) {
    description = "Negative";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 0 && growth_rate < 1) {
    description = "reasonable";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 1 && growth_rate < 2) {
    description = "ambitious";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 2 && growth_rate < 4) {
    description = "high";
  } else {
    description = "unreasonable";
  }

  return description;
}
```

Or you could write the function like

```
const char * get_growth_rate_description(double growth_rate) {

  const char *description = "unreasonable";
  double growth_percentage = growth_rate * 100;

  if (growth_rate < 0) {
    description = "Negative";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 0 && growth_rate < 1) {
    description = "reasonable";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 1 && growth_rate < 2) {
    description = "ambitious";
  } else if (growth_rate >= 2 && growth_rate < 4) {
    description = "high";
  }

  return description;
}
```